# Pyspark to pandas df taking a lot of time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Converting pyspark object to pandas taking hell time. How to store in pandas df?

I have the below code(sample). I am pulling data from pyspark and just then pulling data from teradata,  then finally joining 2 different df in python. However while converting pp_data2  to pandas df taking of around 2 hours.

```
pp_data2 = sqlContext.sql('''SELECT c1,c2,c3 

FROM cstonedb3.pp_data 

where prod in ('7QD','7RJ','7RK','7RL','7RM') ''')

pp_data2 = pp_data2.toPandas()
```

Comment: Just curious- why are you converting PySpark DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: How long does the SQL query take to run without `toPandas`? Where's the underlying data coming from? Have you checked whether the problem is with the query performance, not the conversion?

Comment: if the data is huge, don't convert it to pandas. instead use pyspark to do the computation. what is it exactly you want to do?

Comment: @YOLO i want to do data mugging and in the end also i will in the need to get the pyspark df to be converted into pandas df.